# OWIN OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin

I have read the tutorial http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server and realized that this is what I really want to secure my web APIs. so I downloaded the project code and added to my API's MVC project. Actually my project is divided into 2 parts, the MVC_application (for displaying data from web API's) and the MVC_API where my API's are configured. so now I have three projects (MVC_application, MVC_API and AuthorizationServer)

My question is: Howcan I link the AuthorizationServer to my project?

In other words: how do I tell the application to call AuthorizationServer before calling the MVC_API project to read the data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to secure your web api project, and handle in your mvc project , unauthorized responses from your web api service. For call your web api, you need to **call first to your authorization server**, get the **bearer token** and include the **header** in your subsequent requests to your web api service.